# Copying just files not present with SCP

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I need to move my web server directory to another server. I'd like to do it with a simple "scp -r destination:destdirectory". But in the meanwhile the directory will be filled with another stuff: so I'll take the old server down the time I need to move the newest file to the new one. How can I do an scp which is gonna write just the differences? So it'll take not much time, and I won't have to take the website down for too long!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not at all, or just with pains. But if you have the possibility to use `rsync`, just do that. It automatically excludes files that haven't changed, and for changed files, it just transfers the differences.

Comment: okay, but I often use scp. I really needed a moving of just delta files, cause I can't setup everytime rsync between the machines.